# the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: vb.net

i'm new with ajax/jquery stuff. i'm trying to call function from code behind, got error

> POST HelpdeskParamUserSchedule.aspx/getUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

and description

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

here my code on page

```
function initComboUser() {
        debugger;
        $("#cmbUser").combobox({
            type: "GET",
            url: "HelpdeskParamUserSchedule.aspx/getUser",

            valueField: 'id',
            textField: 'text',
            panelWidth: 300,
            panelHeight: 200



        });
    }
```

here my code in code behind

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getUser() As DataTable
    'Dim ObjDatRelat As ESS.Entities.TList(Of ESS.Entities.MsUser) = ESS.Data.DataRepository.MsUserProvider.GetPaged("FlagIsHelpDeskUser=1", "", 0, Integer.MaxValue, 0)
    Dim detData As New List(Of MsUser)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim com As New SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    strSQL = "select usernip, username from user "
    If Esscon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Esscon.Open()
    Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Esscon)
        dad.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    Return dt

End Function
```

don't know what to do, i get stucked :(

Comment: Suggestion: attach debugger to server and set it to break when `HttpExeception` is thrown. The message tells you something is trying to access a resource above (`..`: parent directory) the root of the web app's directory.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the error message? Or at least put the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `function initComboUser()` should have a `data : <data_value>,` part in it just after the URL value. I think you are missing it.

Once try changing `Type: "POST",`.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but i have add data:"{}", and change type to post, it doesn't help :(